# Use of Options in RESTful Web services

Tags: http, rest, service, web

In RESTful web service, is OPTIONS method is supposed to be used to provide a list of available services? If yes, is that mandatory, or just a good programming practice.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A response to an `OPTIONS` request should provide some information about what the client can do with the resource in question. The most obvious example is to show which methods the resource will respond to, probably using an [`Allow` header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.7). You could also respond with the `Accept-Ranges` header to show when you support range requests.

In practice, though, the `Allow` header is the only common use of the `OPTIONS` method, and even then implementation is far from universal. So it’s a nice feature to have, but isn’t likely to make a huge difference in a real world service.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitively not mandatory but certainly an option.

But keep in mind that to use OPTIONS for service discovery you'll need extension header fields or a custom response media type, in which case GET might work better in practice.